# Can we Customize Sharepoint Online (2016) like Sharepoint 2010 / 2013 on Premise?

Tags: sharepoint-online, customization

I would like to know whether we can customize Sharepoint Online (Office 365) home page? Previously on MS Sharepoint 2010 & 2013, we can customize the masterpages and have our preferences Intranet portal, but I wonder this could be done in new version Sharepoint Online?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can still apply your own master page in SharePoint Online! But it is no longer recommended! Microsoft is frequently rolling out updates that you'll miss out on when not using the built-in master page. Microsoft is on a journey towards a fully responsive design with the new modern look. You would bypass this on sites where you have applyied your own master page.

You should instead focus your efforts on client-side customizations. For example by registering an [alternate CSS file and registering custom JavaScript code](http://www.tonyishere.co.uk/news/tag/alternative-css/) to manipulate the DOM. Then there is also the new [SharePoint Framework](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) that enables you to build and deploy client-side customizations in SharePoint Online. It is 100% client-side and will also not support a custom master page.

Comment: Link to What's not supported with "modern" team sites? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites#whats-not-supported-with-modern-team-sites

Answer (score 1):

You can modify master pages on SharePoint Online by going to

> Look and Feel -> Design manager

For more, read

- [How to: Create Master Page Using Design Manager In SharePoint 2013](http://sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Create-Master-Page-Using-Design-Manager-in-SharePoint-2013)
- [How to: Convert an HTML file into a master page in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822370.aspx)

Comment: Is this applied to **Sharepoint Online (2016)** or just for **Sharepoint 2013**?

Comment: works for both SharePoint version 2013/2016

Comment: search for Modern Experience(s) , Microsoft has disabled any branding  of those

Comment: Thanks Danny for the pointer, but the question was if it is possible and at present it is for sure.

Comment: Yes for future development and customization it is better to stick with latest approach. Please see Lars answer.

Comment: If you can brand the SharePoint Online Modern Experience you would be the intergalactic hero. You can only brand the traditional Masterpage way if you switch back SharePoint online to Classic Mode.. As for branding masterpage.. generic advice since SharePoint Online is to use UserCustomActions (available since SP2010) and not mess with the MasterPage